# Level Shifting a MOSFET

Tags: microcontroller, mosfet-driver, level-shifting, powermosfet

I have a high current low voltage MOSFET I'd like to drive with a higher voltage and a micro to reduce power losses through it. I built this circuit based off the typical level shifting designs. The MOSFET does not turn off. The circuit has been reconstructed twice, and both times the MOSFET works fine before and after, so I don't think I'm breaking anything. Any ideas as to why its not working?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f0K0Uh.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I am a bit new to circuits, so please correct me if I've made some very silly mistake.

edit: source and drain of the 2N7000 should not be connected together like they are in the picture, not sure what happened there - source should connect to the logic signal, drain should connect to the power mosfet

Comment: What steps did you do to debug? Did you check the various nodes by using oscilloscope? If yes, could you post them here

Comment: Any reason you don't want to have the micro drive the gate of Q2, and use it like an external open-drain inverter?

Comment: @ThePhoton That would invert the signal, OP might need this polarity

Comment: @CristobolPolychronopolis, if the signal comes from a micro, it's often pretty easy to invert it in software.

Comment: @ThePhoton Sometimes you don't have the source, but I'm just guessing as to why he wanted a noninverting shifter.

Comment: OP, what voltages do you see on the logic signal and the Q1 gate in the on and off states?  That would give us a lot more to go on when diagnosing.  Is your 3.3V supply really that high, because you're dancing with a max 3V Vgsth on the 2n7000.

Comment: @CristobolPolychronopolis, I'm guessing (because we have a lot of complete beginners who ask questions here) that they just didn't think of the possibility. (But I'm asking questions to confirm my guess, not just assuming it's true)

Comment: @CristobolPolychronopolis So I took some measurements and this is what I saw:

logic low: 0V
logic high: 3.43V
Q1 gate & logic low: 7.44V
Q1 gate & logic high: 7.44V

I'm also not exactly sure I understand what you mean when you say invert the signal (like I said, complete beginner!), Does that mean logic high vs logic low, or a behavior like a not gate?

Comment: Thanks for the responses btw

Comment: Correction: measured again and got different results. I got these more than 5 times so I assume they are the actual readings. Logic low: 0V, logic high: 3.44V, Q1 gate & logic low: 0V, Q1 gate & logic high: 7.44V. Interestingly, the resistance across Q1 changes between logic high and logic low. Not sure if that matters at all, but it goes from ~20 ohms at logic low to 0.03 ohms at logic high. That logic high value corresponds to what the data sheet says for a given VGS

Comment: So if the gate of Q1 is switching from 0V to 7.44V, it looks like everything up to there is working properly.  If Q1 is still conducting with 0V Vgs, it may be damaged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the issue was a dead power mosfet. Replaced the part and the circuit worked fine. I also replaced the 2n7000 with a lower threshold mosfet to make sure it actually switches.

Answer (score 1):

What might be happening is that, during turn-off, voltage drop across 2n7000 might be bigger due to 3.3V dc source being near to 2n7000 threshold voltage(check in datasheet) when it is applied across VGS.

**Edit**:

Explanantion: During turn-off, the charged Q1 gate capacitor has to be discharged and the path following is through the Q2 and logic controller ground. Looking at Q2 datasheet, at VGS = 3.3V, you can get Id = 0.04A(approx, from the ID vs VDS curve). Since Q1 gate current would be discharged at 0.04A causing the turn-off process to be slow. Also the VDS Q2 would increase for cap to discharge slowly since the IdQ2 current cannot increase beyond 0.04A.

Kindly check the signal on oscilloscope at Q1 drain when applying signal. If it follows the same thing, then, we can extend the discussion.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Can you expand on what you mean by "voltage drop across the 2n7000 might be bigger"? Bigger than what?

Comment: One thing I wanted to ask: Is the signal being applied as PWM signal. If yes? At what frequency and duty?

Comment: The signal is not a PWM signal. Its either on or off with either minutes or seconds between a change. To give you some more background, its switching a brushless motor controller module on and off in order to calibration

Comment: Okay. I saw the comment by you when you measured the voltages again. Gate signal at Q1 appears to be proper. Is it still not working properly then?

Comment: As @CristobolPolychronopolis, pointed out in your question, try changing MOSFET, it may have gone bad.(Check if you are not exceeding the current rating and voltage rating of the device before replacing one)

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing inherently wrong with the circuit. It will switch very slowly (which could be hard on the output MOSFET) because of the 100K, but that also limits the current into your MCU output.

Probably your implementation is at fault. Check the pinout on the 2N7000 and the other MOSFET and the resistor values, or take a sharp photo of your circuit and provide any measurements you've made. With the input grounded directly you should see almost no voltage at Q1's gate (relative to ground) and 3.3V on the gate of Q2.

Open circuit at the input and it will stay on. It has to be actively grounded to make it shut off.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I double checked pin outs and values, and they match the schematic I provided. When you say actively grounded, do you mean that there must be some sort of biasing (not sure if thats the correct term here) on the input?

Comment: The input has to be actively pulled to ground, like with a transistor or a switch or a direct connection to ground. Leaving it open will not work.

Comment: Gotcha, so would a push-pull micro output qualify as actively grounded?

Comment: Yes, it would...